# issue with ajax request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax request and it can return one or more rows it depends of what the user selects in the options and then 4 fields are displayed, related of his choice.

When there are two or more rows it's working perfectly but when there is only one rows it does not work at all. The 4 fields are not displayed.

I think it's because of my fetch.

But I do not see how to solve the problem

I hope you will help me. :)

**My php request :**

```
    public function getContactByClient($id2, $id){
    $req = "select contact.nom, prenom, email, telephone from produit 
            inner join clientproduit on clientproduit.idClient = produit.id
            inner join client on client.id = clientproduit.idClient
            inner join contact on contact.id = client.idContact
            where clientproduit.idClient = '$id2' AND clientproduit.idProduit = '$id'";
    $res = PdoGR::$monPdo->query($req);
    $laLigne = $res->fetch();
    return $laLigne;
}
```

**My ajax request :**

```
    $('body').on('change', '#nomClient', function(){

    //on recupere la valeur de l'attribut value pour afficher tel ou tel resultat
    var req2=$('#referenceProduit').val();
    var req=$('#nomClient').val();
    //requête ajax, appel du fichier function.php
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "include/php.php?nomClient="+req+"&referenceProduit="+req2,
        dataType : "html",
        //affichage de l'erreur en cas de problème
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(XMLHttpRequest + '--' + textStatus + '--' + errorThrown);
        },
        //function s'il n'y a pas de probleme
        success:function(data){
            //On affiche la réponse du serveur
            $('.client').empty();
            $('.client').prepend(data);
            $('input[name=nom]').val($('input:hidden[name=nom]').val());
            $('input[name=prenom]').val($('input:hidden[name=prenom]').val());
            $('input[name=telephone]').val($('input:hidden[name=telephone]').val());
            $('input[name=email]').val($('input:hidden[name=email]').val());
            console.log(data)
        }
    });
});
```

**My function.php**

```
if(isset($_GET['nomClient'])){
    $id = $_GET["referenceProduit"];
    $id2 = $_GET["nomClient"];

    $res = $pdo->getContactByClient($id2, $id);

    foreach ($res as $key => $value) {
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="'.$key.'" value="'.$value.'"/>';
    }

    echo '
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="nomContact" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Nom</label>
          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nom" id="nom" readonly>
          </div>
          <label for="prenomContact" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Prénom</label>
          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="prenom" id="prenom" readonly>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="emailContact" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Email</label>
          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" readonly>
          </div>
          <label for="telephoneContact" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Téléphone</label>
          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="telephone" id="telephone" readonly>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    ';
}
```

Comment: `return $laLigne;`  in function `getContactByClient` did you print the value of `$laLigne`. Is it returning one row??.  If it is returning correct data then the problem is not with `fetch`

Comment: when there is only one choice nothing happens, but when there are two or more datas are correct